# Django template tag: How to send next_page in {url auth_logout}?

Tags: django

I have an urls.py with this line:

```
url(r'^logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', name="auth_logout"),
```

In my template tag i have this line:

```
<a href="{% url auth_logout %}">Logout</a>
```

Now, I would like to add the next_page param to the url templatetag, but I can't get it to work. I have tried this:

```
{% url auth_logout request.path %}"
```

...and this:

```
{% url auth_logout request,request.path %}
```

But none of them works. How can I provide the function with the optional next_page paramter usinging the url templatetag?

Thanks!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Two things:

1. django.contrib.auth.views.logout() takes an optional next_page which you are not providing
2. url templatetag has comma-separated arguments

So, first **modify your url** to accept next_page
Your URLConf needs modification to pass in the next page, something like this for a hard-coded redirect:

```
url(r'^logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', {'next_page': '/'}, name='auth_logout'),
```

and one parameterized result:

```
url(r'^logout/(?P<next_page>.*)/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', name='auth_logout_next'),
```

And then **modify your template** to pass in the next_page

```
<a href="{% url auth_logout_next /some/location %}">Logout</a>
```

- [Docs on logout](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#other-built-in-views)
- [Docs on url templatetag](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url)

Comment: That almost does the trick! Having two lines in urls.py solves it, but brings up the django default loutout page when just entering /logout/.

Adding

    {'next_page': '/'}
as you suggest causes the redirect to go / in all cases, even when next is specified. Viewing the source code for logout explains that behaviour.

So it appears, the parameterized one is used by the template tag, but the hard-coded on is used when the link is actually clicked?

Answer (score 28):

For what it's worth, I use this:

```
<a href="{% url auth_logout %}?next=/">Logout</a>
```

Comment: That worked for me, except I left out the quotes: <a href={% url admin:logout %}?next=/>

Comment: This is the simplest solution. I don't understand why everyone's upvoting the solution that requires adding specialized url patterns...

Comment: @Amyth, That has nothing to do with a url pattern. Both hardcode the `next` parameter, even though they could easily replace it with the meta path...

Answer (score 9):

Sander Smits has the most easy solution. In your case use:

```
<a href="{% url "auth_logout" %}?next={{ request.path|urlencode }}">Logout</a>
```

And in a more general case, use:

```
<a href="{% url "auth_logout" %}?next={% url "my_url" my_params |urlencode %}">Logout</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone wants to give out an HTML link through views.py validation error with mark_safe and translations.

I used this part to logout the user and then send him to the password recorve page.

```
mark_safe(_("Error message") + '<a href="' + reverse('logout') + '?next=' + reverse('password_recover') + '">' + ugettext("Forgot password?") + '</a>')
```